# Shapefile CRS conundrum

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS I have two  vector layer shapefiles which should overlay approximately one on the other.  They have both been downloaded from the same government website (data.vic.gov.au) with the same projection (GDA94 Zone 55).  When loaded into QGIS they show the same CRS (EPSG:28355) which is also the project CRS, "on the fly" projection is on,  the content of their .prj and .qpj files is identical.  However when loaded they appear on the screen many kilometres apart.

What is going on?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the layers? also, you can add a link to the data so others can take a look and try to identify the problem

Comment: Please post the extents of both layers. Guess: One is using GDA94 / VICGRID94.

Comment: Sorry I raised this when about to travel OS for 5 weeks.  I don't have time to follow up with more detail until I return.  Thank you to all who have offered to help.  Will add more on my return.